# Don't understand the solution of "Bright dots in the pre-filter convolution" in learnopengl.com

Tags: math, opengl

I don't understand the solution code of "Bright dots in the pre-filter convolution" in https://learnopengl.com/PBR/IBL/Specular-IBL, especially the PDF(possibility density function) part.

here is the code

```
float D   = DistributionGGX(NdotH, roughness);
float pdf = (D * NdotH / (4.0 * HdotV)) + 0.0001; 

float resolution = 512.0; // resolution of source cubemap (per face)
float saTexel  = 4.0 * PI / (6.0 * resolution * resolution);
float saSample = 1.0 / (float(SAMPLE_COUNT) * pdf + 0.0001);

float mipLevel = roughness == 0.0 ? 0.0 : 0.5 * log2(saSample / saTexel);
```

I don't know why does `(D * NdotH / (4.0 * HdotV)) + 0.0001` come from. And why does `saTexel` and `saSample` calculated by this way.

Comment: I recommend to read the complete tutorial (starting at [Theory](https://learnopengl.com/PBR/Theory)). Everything is well explained there. What you ask for seems to be off-topic, because it is to broad.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Well, I will try your advice, thank you anyway